# Narrowing a generic callable definition

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I want to define a custom type, using a `ParamSpec` and `TypeVar` that can then be narrowed as necessary depending on where it is used.

I've defined a custom generic type that represents either a function or coroutine function that takes some amount of arguments and returns a value.

```
_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_R = TypeVar("_R")
FunctionOrCoroutine = Union[Callable[_P, _R], Callable[_P, Awaitable[_R]]]
```

I then want to be able to narrow it when used in a more specific place, e.g. where I need a function/coroutine function that takes no arguments and returns a string

```
def foo(callback_fn: FunctionOrCoroutine[[], str]):
    pass
```

The above works in Python 3.10 but when I try this on 3.9 (using the `typing-extensions` backport to get access to `ParamSpec`), I get the following error:

> TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got [].

What am I doing wrong here? I don't understand why this would work on 3.10, but not on 3.9, even with the `ParamSpec` backported. Are there any workarounds? Am I just misunderstanding something fundamental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations! You just discovered a bug in `typing_extensions`. Compare the definition of `typing._GenericAlias.__getitem__` in `3.9` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c25b484e82cace132a5f3c89b69888eaf7b1d40e/Lib/typing.py#L760)) and the same definition in `3.10` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6c2e052ee07f10a6336bb4de1cef71dbe7d30ee6/Lib/typing.py#L1047)). Here's an extract:

```
# 3.9
class _GenericAlias(_BaseGenericAlias, _root=True):
    @_tp_cache
    def __getitem__(self, params):
        if self.__origin__ in (Generic, Protocol):
            # Can't subscript Generic[...] or Protocol[...].
            raise TypeError(f"Cannot subscript already-subscripted {self}")
        if not isinstance(params, tuple):
            params = (params,)
        msg = "Parameters to generic types must be types."
        params = tuple(_type_check(p, msg) for p in params)  # <<< Here
        _check_generic(self, params, len(self.__parameters__))

        subst = dict(zip(self.__parameters__, params))
        new_args = []
        for arg in self.__args__:
            if isinstance(arg, TypeVar):
                arg = subst[arg]
            elif isinstance(arg, (_GenericAlias, GenericAlias)):
                subparams = arg.__parameters__
                if subparams:
                    subargs = tuple(subst[x] for x in subparams)
                    arg = arg[subargs]
            new_args.append(arg)
        return self.copy_with(tuple(new_args))
```

```py
# 3.10
class _GenericAlias(_BaseGenericAlias, _root=True):
    @_tp_cache
    def __getitem__(self, params):
        if self.__origin__ in (Generic, Protocol):
            # Can't subscript Generic[...] or Protocol[...].
            raise TypeError(f"Cannot subscript already-subscripted {self}")
        if not isinstance(params, tuple):
            params = (params,)
        params = tuple(_type_convert(p) for p in params)
        if (self._paramspec_tvars
                and any(isinstance(t, ParamSpec) for t in self.__parameters__)):
            params = _prepare_paramspec_params(self, params)
        else:
            _check_generic(self, params, len(self.__parameters__))

        subst = dict(zip(self.__parameters__, params))
        new_args = []
        for arg in self.__args__:
            if isinstance(arg, self._typevar_types):
                if isinstance(arg, ParamSpec):  # <<< Now it's special cased
                    arg = subst[arg]
                    if not _is_param_expr(arg):
                        raise TypeError(f"Expected a list of types, an ellipsis, "
                                        f"ParamSpec, or Concatenate. Got {arg}")
                else:
                    arg = subst[arg]
            elif isinstance(arg, (_GenericAlias, GenericAlias, types.UnionType)):
                subparams = arg.__parameters__
                if subparams:
                    subargs = tuple(subst[x] for x in subparams)
                    arg = arg[subargs]
            # Required to flatten out the args for CallableGenericAlias
            if self.__origin__ == collections.abc.Callable and isinstance(arg, tuple):
                new_args.extend(arg)
            else:
                new_args.append(arg)
        return self.copy_with(tuple(new_args))
```

Comments starting with `<<<` are mine.

`Callable` relies on `_GenericAlias` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6c2e052ee07f10a6336bb4de1cef71dbe7d30ee6/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L572)), and thus the behaviour is different.

I don't see related issue on `typing_extensions` tracker, so please consider opening a new one - the only solution I can imagine would be to add `Callable` to `typing_extensions` too, but maybe the core team can think of something better. Alternatively, this can be considered a grammar change and not be backported via `typing-extensions` at all.

To work around this issue you can simply use string annotations or `annotations` future-import (`from __future__ import annotations`), the latter is preferred IMO, but doesn't work in `cast` and other runtime-executed cases, where you'll need string annotations anyway. So, both of the following should work:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

...
# Yes, nothing to change here!
def foo(callback_fn: FunctionOrCoroutine[[], str]):
    pass
```

```py
...
def foo(callback_fn: 'FunctionOrCoroutine[[], str]'):
    pass
```